# Using Lambda to call Amazon Rekognition on uploaded images

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

Does anyone know if it is possible to use Lambda to call Rekognition functions when an image is uploaded to an S3 Bucket?

I am looking at integrating a Raspberry Pi device with a Pi Cam to take photos and do some face recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure an Event on Amazon S3 to call a lambda function that can be either in C#, Java, Python or NodeJS.

For details, see: [Tutorial: Creating an Amazon Rekognition Lambda Application](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-rekognition-example.html)

Comment: I was reading how to send SMS using Lambda with Twilio, I can't seem to find how to trigger a Lambda function based on the feedback of the Recognition Tags placed on the images.

Comment: The example you have mentioned is based on visual studio specificly.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these instructions for a complete walk through on how to do exactly that: https://github.com/markwest1972/smart-security-camera